# Debugging - logging database queries

Tags: database, logging

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
define('SAVEQUERIES', true);
```

these are lines from my wp-config.php file. What I expect now, that I can view a log file after I click around on my site. I don't find anything, especially no debug.log file in wp-contents. Is there anything else I have to do?

Comment: Check if there is a permission error to create a file in the `wp-content` directory for the server user.

Comment: no, there is not

Comment: If you expected to see the queries, `SAVEQUERIES` only "saves" them in the `$wpdb` object, you need to log them yourself, [see example](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#WP_DEBUG_LOG).

Comment: you can also see the queries with this plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/

Comment: See also this SO answer for a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4660903/1086134

Answer (score 1):

The debug log will only capture PHP-generated errors as well as things you manually send yourself. So if it is not being created right now, then there are no warnings/errors being generated by PHP right now.

In order to send things manually, you use `error_log()`. One quick note though is that you have to set echo to `true` if you use functions like `print_r()` to dump out arrays and such to see the actual contents, otherwise you'll just get a `1` so you'll want something like:

```
error_log( '--- $_POST ---' . PHP_EOL );
error_log( print_r( $_POST, true ) );
error_log( '--- End $_POST ---' . PHP_EOL );
```

This way you have some landmarks you can search for in the log. `PHP_EOL` is a constant that simply inserts `\n` for you so the log will have a line break.